# how to convert list of arrays of same legth

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

if I convert a list of arrays (the internal arrays have all the same length) in an array of arrays, python converts it as a matrix with all the elements joined together. I want it to always remain an array of arrays. Here's what happens:

```
list_1 = [[np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([4,5,6])]]

>>> np.array(list_1)
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]]])
```

but I would have:

```
>>> np.array(list_1)
array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5,6])], dtype=object)
```

how can I achive this?

Comment: that's not concerned my question, man. Sorry

Comment: I illustrate a method at the end of my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/54760478. Make a object array of the right size, and fill it from your list.  Some times it's tricky to avoid broadcasting errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
list_1 = [[np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([4,5,6])]]
l = np.array(list_1)
print(l.tolist())
```

result:

[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]

Answer (score 1):

```
In [20]: list_1 = [[np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([4,5,6])]]
```

Allocate a object dtype array of right size:

```
In [27]: arr = np.empty(2, object)
```

Copy values from list to that array:

```
In [28]: arr[:] = list_1[0]                                                     
In [29]: arr                                                                    
Out[29]: array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

Sometimes broadcasting causes problems with this kind of copy, and I've had to fall back on a more explicit iteration:

```
In [30]: for i in range(2): 
    ...:     arr[i] = list_1[0][i]
```

Your `list_1` has an extra set of brackets, hence the need to use `list_1[0]`.

The recent question that I linked in the comment has a number of good answers as to why `np.array(list_1)` normally produces a 2d (actually 3d) array.